# Cómo recorrer un datagridview y que guarde las filas que tengan el chechbox seleccionado, en c# con visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

estoy haciendo un modulo de una aplicación la cual consta de:
- Un botón que va a buscar información a una base de datos
- un datagridvew, que refleja la información de la tabla
- un checkbox que va a tener cada fila, este lo agregué de forma "global", con este código y tiene la particularidad de que me agrega un checkbox en el header de la tabla y puedo seleccionar o deseleccionar todos:

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddHeaderCheckBox();
    HeaderCheckbox.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(HeaderCheckBox_MouseClick);

}
//se agrega headercheckbox
CheckBox HeaderCheckbox = null;
bool IsHeaderCheckBoxClicked = false;

private void AddHeaderCheckBox()
{
    HeaderCheckbox = new CheckBox();
    HeaderCheckbox.Size = new Size(15, 15);
    HeaderCheckbox.Location = new Point(15,10); ;
    this.dataGridView1.Controls.Add(HeaderCheckbox);
}

private void HeaderCheckBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HeaderCheckBoxClick((CheckBox)sender);
}

//se controla el click en el checkbox
private void HeaderCheckBoxClick(CheckBox Chck)
{
    IsHeaderCheckBoxClicked = true;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)Row.Cells["check"]).Value = Chck.Checked;
    }
    dataGridView1.RefreshEdit();
    IsHeaderCheckBoxClicked = false;
}
```

Lo que llevo hasta ahora es que me muestra la información como corresponde y todas las filas tienen un checkbox al inicio.

Cual es mi idea: si tengo 10 filas cada una va con su checkbox, si selecciono por ejemplo el numero 2 y 6 tengo que enviar la información de estas filas a un procedimiento almacenado, pongo una imagen para que quede más clara la idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo claro que la acción se va a llevar es en el botón **Procesar** pero ando un poco perdido en como programarlo, tiene que ser del tipo: "recorre el datagridview y donde veas que el check es verdadero guárdame los datos en Listas(por ejemplo)" Creo que mi mayor problema es en decirle que recorra el datagridview, lo otro es poner una condición y guardar.

¿Cómo se hace esto?

Muchas Gracias

---

Buscando un poco encontré este código:

```
private void btn_procesar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)r.Cells[0].Value;
        if (ck.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(r.Cells[1].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Pero me tira error de:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Boolean' al tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te marca el error porque como bien lo dice estás tratando de convertir un valor boolean (true o false) en un objeto como lo es checkbox que tiene muchas propiedades y métodos.

Para revisar si el check está seleccionado basta con convertir value a boolean:

```
private void btn_procesar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[0].Value);
        if (isChecked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(r.Cells[1].ToString());
            // Aquí podrías almacenar los valores de esta fila, y seguir recorriendo el grid
            // ó podrías ejecutar el stored de una vez.
            // Depende de lo que veas más factible como desarrollador de la aplicación 
            // y las reglas de negocio que se tengan
        }
    }
}
```

Ojalá te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Si me sirvió, muchas gracias